# When saving a document or editing a file name, with the focus on the string itself, why does CMD+Delete move the file or folder to the trash?

Tags: finder, trash, macos

To be more specific, I am saving a file from my markdown editor. Within the save dialog box, I navigate to the folder I wish to save the file. I then decide to change the name of the file. I put my cursor at the end of the text string and hit CMD + Delete. The expected behavior is to delete the entire string. Instead, this deletes the previously selected folder I highlighted in the dialog box.

Typically, I expect CMD + Delete to remove an entire line of text. I also tested this with renaming a file. If my focus is on the string name of the file, why would CMD+delete remove the file, when Option+Delete removes individual words as expected.

I can do screen shots or short movie if this is confusing. I don't recall this happening previously but I'm not often creating files outside of Python.

13" rMBP using 10.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file name is highlighted then just use Delete, not the CMD+Delete.

The CMD+Delete will also delete the file on my MBA with 10.9.5 Finder.

Comment: The downside to what you recommended is that for Delete alone to remove all the text I have to have it all highlighted. Delete removes it character by character unless I have everything selected. It just goes against the behavior I'm used to in every other instance when I'm manipulating strings.  Thanks!

Comment: It is actually simple, just double click (slow click, otherwise it will open the file) on the file name to highlight all.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just curious about why the default behavior of CMD+Delete when the focus is a string (file name, saving a file, folder name, or bit of code in Sublime) is different in the Finder than other places.

The basic conclusion is just don't use CMD+Delete when dealing with file names. Thanks!

Comment: I agree, but in the File menu the cmd+delete is the "move to trash", why it does that when you just want to change the name text? well that's another story :)

Answer (score 0):

when saving a file, by default the entire name excluding .extension ought to be selected, so just starting to type will rename it.

To navigate,

- forward arrow will go to the end of the filename, before the extension
- up arrow [or back arrow initially, until the fully-selected name is 'broken'] will go to the beginning,
- down arrow to the end, if you want to accept the original name but add prefix/suffix etc

Comment: It basically adds a few more keys to my 'normal' workflow for deleting a line. For unhighlighted things, I'll just have to be more careful when deleting. Thanks!